# How can I use a * as text in a SED?

Tags: sed, terminal

I am trying to replace `CEName.objects.create(**name_data)` with `self.create()` like this:

```
sed 's/CEName.objects.create(**name_data)/self.create()/g'
```

Except it doesn't like the `*`. How can I escape them to make this work?

Comment: use `\*` to match `*` literally.. also, `.` is a metacharacter, so you need `\.` (also this applies in your case only in search section, replacement section has lot less metacharacters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` and `*` needs to be interpreted literally,so the characters `.` and `*` need to be quoted by preceding them by a backslash `\`.

Check here: [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

```
sed 's/CEName\.objects\.create(\*\*name_data)/self\.create()/g'
```

Output:

```
self.create()
```